# Australian Tax Digital Nomad

Tags: income-tax, australia, new-zealand

I am a NZ citizen working for an Australian company being paid into an Australian bank account through an Australian tax number and visiting Australia every 4-6 weeks for 3-4 days work related. I hardly ever visit NZ. I am living off shore in neither of these countries, what tax classification do I fall under? And what would be the best way to position myself?

Comment: Where do you actually live?

Comment: Have you asked the tax authorities in either country?

Comment: If you are getting paid in Australia you will have to file your tax return there. You need to find out if you are classed as a tax resident for tax purposes and you will need to find out what country is your main residency in, Then you will need to find out if there is any tax treaty between Australia and where your main residency is. So you haven't provided enough information for anyone to answer this question properly.

Comment: Note that you are likely (also?) taxable in your country of residence. Citizenship basically only matters for taxes in the US & Eritrea.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon Some countries tax everything earned within their borders...  US taxes citizens no matter where they reside, all residents who earn in the US, and I assume non-residents who earn inside the US.

Comment: Hey everyone thanks for you help - When I say living, I mean semi travelling (digital nomad) around Indonesia and China. I don't properly reside anywhere currently. They've classified me as a non-resident for tax purposes in Australia. But no-one really seems to know including the tax authorities. I also get paid super in AU. If I was an Australian citizen it would make it easier, but because I'm from NZ that's where the confusion lies.

Comment: @Xalorous Yes, this is what I was saying. The OP hadn't provided residence information, and I was also pointing out that NZ citizenship matters little [except perhaps as a tool to help determine residency].